# can't activate windows 7 with windows 7 service pack 1 key

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

I installed windows 7 without service pack 1 and now, when I'm trying to input service pack 1 key, I get an [error](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Windows-7-activation-error-invalid-product-key). Can I activate it when I simply install service pack 1 or I need to reinstall it from image with service pack 1?

Comment: Was this a fresh install?  Is your key from an UPGRADE instead of a full retail?  Is the Key from OEM (came with your computer)?  Any chance your key is for Starter/Home/Pro/Enterprise and you installed a different version?

Comment: Yep, fresh install, key is from dreamspark premium.

Comment: I understand that it's from Dreakspark, but what for version of windows ("dreamspark premium" is vague)?  Which did you install?  Might as well try JustinD's suggestion to see if it works.  Shouldn't take terribly long.

Comment: I installed from iso I burnt about a year and a half ago which I took from MSDN AA (previous name of dreamspark).

Comment: You need to update to Service Pack 1 to use a Service Pack 1 Windows 7 authentication key. Why don't you simply use the key you recieved when you downloaded the original iso?

Comment: Cause I'm installing it for another person which has its own key.

Comment: The disc from Dreamspark is Win7 Pro (which was one of my questions).  What version of Windows is their key for?

Comment: They are only for windows 7 with service pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, try downloading the Windows 7 service packs manually. Then activating using your key.

I don't know if you have either a 32-bit OS or a 64-bit, so here's both.

[32-Bit](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/A/F/0AFB5316-3062-494A-AB78-7FB0D4461357/windows6.1-KB976932-X86.exe)

[64-Bit](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/A/F/0AFB5316-3062-494A-AB78-7FB0D4461357/windows6.1-KB976932-X64.exe)

Comment: After I installed service pack, I could activate windows.

Comment: Alright, sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently when using Microsoft SA volume licensing. It seems that the ISO needs to be Windows 7 with SP1 or you will not be able to activate it. You should have no trouble finding that install if you look hard enough.

Comment: Hm, sounds bad. Strange politics from Microsoft - what is the difference between OS and OS with patch?

Comment: Beats me. I burned several DVD's before I figured this one out. The straight Win 7 Pro disc resulted in a message to the effect of "This version of Windows 7 cannot be activated." We also have MAK versions available that require an activation server, which being a mostly Apple shop, we don't have. Very annoying.